# Build failed for Next 13 because of incorrect aliases

Tags: next.js

I build my NextJS 13 project with GitLab pipeline but I obtain an error on `npm run build` :

[image]

Here is my tsconfig.json config file for TypeScript and I'm on NodeJS 18.18.0.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The locally build works (with `npm run build`), but on GitLab pipeline, it fails.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .next/cache/

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:18-alpine
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: "production"
  before_script:
    - apk add --update bash
    - apk add --update git && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*
    - apk add --no-cache g++ make py3-pip libc6-compat
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run build
```